# Deep learning evaluation result

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution, keras

A CNN model in Keras gave me the following result.

Code:

```
result = model.evaluate_generator(test_data, verbose=1)
print('test loss: {:.4f}'.format(result[0]))
print(' test accuracy: {:.4f}'.format(result[1]))
```

Result:

```
test loss: 3.9236
test accuracy: 0.4659
```

What do the loss and accuracy mean?

Is the accuracy  0.4659 *10 = 4.659% or 0.4659 * 100 = 46.59%?

Comment: I'm looking in the documentation for Keras.. The return for `evaluate_generator` says *Scalar test loss (if the model has a single output and no metrics) or list of scalars (if the model has multiple outputs and/or metrics). The attribute model.metrics_names will give you the display labels for the scalar outputs.* How many classes are in your model?

Comment: Without further details, I'd say you are using a loss function and have attached an accuracy metric to run each time the function is called. I'd have to know what accuracy function you are using but to answer your second question it is most likely 46.59%. But again, I'd need to know details to confirm.

Comment: Thanks @Sam for replying..  The model has 450 classes. I am using this loss and accuracy >> model.compile(
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),
        metrics=['accuracy']
    )

Comment: OK. So you test loss is the value of the cross entropy function at the current point and the accuracy is calculated as `K.mean(K.equal(K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1), K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)))`